# How to query nested json attribute on postgres / ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

My json for an attribute in a record looks as so:

```
 { foo: bar,   
   foo1: [{key1: value, key2: value},
         {key1: value, key2: value}]
  }
```

i can query for foo just fine by using

```
Model.where("attribute->>'foo' = ?", "bar")
```

Having some trouble querying for values in in key1 and key2

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here [postrgeSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

You can use this operator `#>>` to perform what you need, as the link says 'Get JSON object at specified path as text', for example:

```
'{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}'::json#>>'{a,2}'

Model.where("attribute#>>'{foo1, key1}' = ?", "bar")
```

You should just adapt to your needs now. Hope it helped!

Comment: I am still getting back an empty array when querying with this criteria. Does it matter if i have hashes within the array? e.g. your example is "a": [1,2,3], mine would be "a":[{1:2}, {3:4}]

Comment: Have you tried to use this operator #>, instead ? At the link that I posted it shows an example to retrieve the hash value.